# Histogram bars not visible for extreme values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a scale-free distribution with very extreme values and for some reason they appear almost invisible, both with pyplot and seaborn. Changing color type and transparency did not help. Why does this happen and how can I avoid it? How can I set a uniform color for all the bars?

[image: seaborn]

[image: pyplot]

Comment: The images are actually really helpful here, but copy paste also your code here, so people can more easily try it.

Comment: Make the edgecolor black.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the white outlines of the bars that obfuscates the inside color of the bars when they get too narrow.

I would suggest not drawing the outlines at all by using `linewidth=0` in your call to `distplot()` or `hist()`